How much of his battle suit power is Isao Shinomiya able to release?
In the Kaiju no 8 wikia, it is stated how much of their battle suit powers most of the main characters are able to release, Kikoru Shinomiya, Gen Narumi, Soshiro Hoshina, Mina Ashiro, Leno Ichikawa, etc. However, it isnt stated how much of his battle suit power the most powerful character of all the humans is able to release, Isao Shinomiya.
How much of his battle suit power is Isao Shinomiya able to release?
